# React & Redux MapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm building a React application with Redux for state management. My app allows users to register and purchase a subscription. I want to show details of the subscription in a 'MY ACCOUNT' page and display JOIN NOW call to action for users who haven't subscribed.

When a user logs in I make a call to the database for a subscription collection ad if it exists it's added to the store.

I'm using the code below to map my state to props in the MY ACCOUNT page but I keep getting an error 'subscription.currentSubscription is NULL' when someone logs in without a subscription.... Yet I need the mapping to show subscribed users the details...

How do you handle this scenario?

thanks

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, join, subscription }) => ({
    currentUser: user.currentUser,
    joinStage: join.joinStep,
    priceData: subscription.currentSubscription.priceData,
    subscriptionData: subscription.currentSubscription.subscriptionData,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you narrow the `subscription` as below?

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, join, subscription }) => ({
    currentUser: user.currentUser,
    joinStage: join.joinStep,
    subscription: subscription.currentSubscription
});
```

And in your code logic, before use it just check `subscription`.

```
  const App = ({ subscription }) => {
    if (!subscription) return null
     
    return subscription.priceData
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `subscription.currentSubscription` is null or undefined then it will throw an error when attempting to access deeper into state.

You can use Optional Chaining to guard against null/undefined accesses:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, join, subscription }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
  joinStage: join.joinStep,
  priceData: subscription?.currentSubscription?.priceData,
  subscriptionData: subscription?.currentSubscription?.subscriptionData,
});
```

Or use more conventional null check/guard clauses:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, join, subscription }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
  joinStage: join.joinStep,
  priceData: subscription
    && subscription.currentSubscription
    && subscription.currentSubscription.priceData,
  subscriptionData: subscription
    && subscription.currentSubscription
    && subscription.currentSubscription.subscriptionData,
});
```

Some of this is a bit redundant, so you can do the check *before* returning the mapped state.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, join, subscription }) => {
  const {
    priceData,
    subscriptionData,
  } = subscription?.currentSubscription || {};

  return {
    currentUser: user.currentUser,
    joinStage: join.joinStep,
    priceData,
    subscriptionData,
  }
};
```